# Default field value if a condition satisfies in Azure Stream Analytics SAQL

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I have a requirement to set value of one field as per value of another field available in the document.

Below is the SAQL which I tried for obtaining the requirement.

```
WITH INPUT01 AS (
    SELECT
        input.id AS ID,
        ROUND(input.sig,5) AS SIG,
        input.dtcTriggeredDateTime.dateTime.time AS TIME,
        input.Description as DESC
        FROM [inputsignals] as input
    WHERE GetArrayLength(input.abc) =0 AND (input.Description = 'xyz' OR input.Description = 'pqr')

SELECT 
    ID,
    SIG,
    TIME,
    001 AS NUMID 
INTO [cosmosDB]
FROM INPUT01
WHERE DESC = 'abc'

SELECT 
    ID,
    SIG,
    TIME,
    002 AS NUMID 
INTO [cosmosDB]
FROM INPUT01
WHERE DESC = 'pqr'
```

If the DESC is **abc** then **NUMID** should be **001** and if DESC is **pqr** then **NUMID** should be **002**.

Instead of writing the last two select statements separately is there any options to write it in a single SELECT query as something like below?

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    SIG,
    TIME,
    001 AS NUMID  (If DESC = abc)
    002 AS NUMID  (If DESC = pqr)
INTO [cosmosDB]
FROM INPUT01
```

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: yes..it works fine only with ELSE part also. Thank you@Jay Gong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [CASE...WHEN...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/case-azure-stream-analytics) operator in SA SQL:

```
SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN DESC = 'abc' THEN 001
      WHEN DESC = 'pqr' THEN 002 
   END as NUMID  
FROM INPUT01
```